# Texture mapping and resizing a sphere primitive in Mathematica

Tags: graphics3d, textures

**Background Info**

In Mathematica, it's only possible to texture map a sphere through the use of `SphericalPlot3D` or `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
image = Import["MyTexture.jpg"]; (* Pretend this is something you'd use *)

sphere = SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Mesh -> None, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &),
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[image]],
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];
```

Now that's all nice and everything. But what if we want multiple spheres on the same exact image, each with an arbitrary size? To [position a single sphere is simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8695995/312124):

```
s1 = Graphics3D[
 Translate[First@sphere, {3, 2, 1}],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Then you just position each sphere and `Show` them together:

```
Show[{s1, s2}, PlotRange->{{-5, +5}, {-5, +5}, {-5, +5}}]
```

---

**The Issue**

That's great and all, but **what if you need each sphere to be a distinct size**? Positioning and sizing regular `Sphere[]` primitives is easy and built directly into their definition.

But if I want the same for a *textured* sphere, I have to jump through all these hoops. Furthermore, it's not obvious how I can achieve this.

Any ideas on how I can achieve arbitrary placement and sizing of *textured* spheres?

Comment: I just added a comment to Heike's answer and should put it here, too: replace `Directive[Texture[image]]` by `Directive[Texture[ImageData@image]]`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a combination of `Translate` and `Scale`. Suppose the radii and centres of the circles are given by

```
radii = RandomReal[{.1, .6}, 8];
centres = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {8, 3}];
```

Then using the original sphere

```
image = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "GiraffeFur"}];
sphere = SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[image]], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];
```

You could do for example

```
Graphics3D[MapThread[Translate[Scale[sphere[[1]], #1], #2] &, {radii, centres}]]
```

Which produces something like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Scale is nice:)

Comment: D'oh. Graphics in Mathematica is wonderful, but it's never obvious how you can do things.

Comment: Just saw that this is still suffering from a little texture bug: Try exporting to `PDF`: the texture looks wrong. To fix it, you can replace `Directive[Texture[image]]` by `Directive[Texture[ImageData@image]]`. That's also how to make transparent textures work properly.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe begin with something like

```
sphere /. 
  GraphicsComplex[pts_, others__] :> 
   GraphicsComplex[1.1 pts, others] // Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```