# Density plot on the surface of sphere

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to make density plots of a list of (size 2 or 3) spherical harmonics on the surface of a sphere.  I'd like to plot it so that each element of that list is using a different color (red density plot for the first one, blue for the next, green... and so on)

I tried using `ColorFunction` like

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
   RGBColor[Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, ϕ]]^2, 
    Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, θ, ϕ]]^2, 
    Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, θ, ϕ]]^2]]]
```

but all I get is some dark-green sphere.  Is there a function like `SphericalDensityPlot` so that I can illustrate the functions?

Also, a big problem I'm running into is the ambient lighting direction, which interferes with what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52/texture-mapping-and-resizing-a-sphere-primitive-in-mathematica) post/answer that might be of help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Instead of individually controlling the RGB colors, which is much harder, use the output of your function (a scalar) as the input to some color function.

Here's an example:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {Φ, 0, 2 π}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, Φ, r}, 
         ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Cos[5 θ] + Cos[4 Φ]/2]], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Your original function didn't have much variability. Specifically, it doesn't vary in Φ and very little in θ. You can see it in this `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
    Graphics[{
        RGBColor[
            Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, Φ]]^2, 
            Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, θ, Φ]]^2, 
            Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, θ, Φ]]^2
        ], 
        Disk[]
    }], 
    {θ, 0, 2 π}, {Φ, 0, 2 π}
]
```

Comment: Did you add e.g. `PlotPoints -> 200` to produce your first graphic, or does v8 output that smooth result by default? (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not by default :) I increased it in my figure above, but left it out in the code because it'd unnecessarily slow things down

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, that's a common problem with using solid textures; to get really smooth-looking colors, you need to use a large number of polygons (and thus, a large value of `PlotPoints`). The advantage is that the colors "fit" naturally; you do not have to reckon formulae for mapping a flat image into your surface. (Some of the previous Perlin noise-related work I've done before required lots of `PlotPoints` and lots of time for rendering, for instance.)

Comment: @rm-rf I'm confused about how `ColorFunctionScaling->False` works in your first code. Why you want to add this? Besides, for the documentation of `ColorFunctionScaling`, it mentions "specifies whether arguments supplied to a color function should be scaled to lie between 0 and 1." Why does this `scale` in the context matter?

Answer (score 31):

**=== Update - all color gradients ===**

You should check out some of the [related Demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=spherical%20harmonics). This is my version - a close reproduction of [Wikipedia figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spherical_harmonics.png) found on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#List_of_spherical_harmonics). Note, $l \geq |m|$ conditions is imposed. The code is below the image.

[image]

```
Manipulate[If[m > l, m = l];
 Column[{
   (* formula *)
   TraditionalForm@SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ],
   (* graphics *)
   SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π},
    ColorFunction -> (gradients[
        t (.5 + f[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, #4, #5]])] &),
    Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotPoints -> 100, SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> .3, 
    ImageSize -> 400]
   }, Alignment -> Center],
 (* controls *)
 {{l, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Setter},
 {{m, 2}, 0, 10, 1, Setter},
 {{f, Re}, {Re, Im, Abs}},
 {{t, 1.2, "focus"}, .5, 1.5, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Small}, {{gradients, 
   ColorData[
    "Rainbow"]}, (ColorData[#] -> 
      Show[ColorData[#, "Image"], ImageSize -> 100]) & /@ 
   ColorData["Gradients"]},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

**=== Simpler older version using `Hue` ===**

```
Manipulate[If[m > l, m = l]; 
 SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[f[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, #4, #5]] - .7] &), 
  Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> .3], {{l, 5}, 0, 10, 1, 
  Setter}, {{m, 2}, 0, 10, 1, Setter}, {{f, Re}, {Re, Im, Abs}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool! Add a choice of color schemes, and then we're cooking! :D

Answer (score 28):

An alternative to R.M's method that became available in version eight is the `Texture[]` directive, which allows one to wrap textures on surfaces. For this application, we can wrap the output of `DensityPlot[]` (after some post-processing with `Image[]`) on a sphere. One benefit to this approach is that `DensityPlot[]` takes care of scaling the spherical harmonics before feeding their values to the `ColorFunction`.

For instance, to use $\Re(Y_\ell^m(\theta,\phi))$ as the texture, we can do this:

```
ReYDensityPlot[ℓ_Integer, m_Integer] := Block[{ymap, θ, ϕ},
  ymap = Image[DensityPlot[
               Re[SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, m, θ, ϕ]] // Evaluate,
                        {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
               ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> False, 
               ImagePadding -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
               PlotPoints -> 55, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
               ImageResolution -> 144];
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]},
                   {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
                   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[ymap], 
                   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)]]
```

Note the use of `Lighting -> "Neutral"` so that all lights used for the surface are white.

(I know I could have used `SphericalPlot3D[]`, but I wanted an explicit reminder of the coordinate system convention being used, as I am more accustomed to using $\theta$ as longitude and $\varphi$ as co-latitude.)

Now, pictures!

```
GraphicsGrid[Table[ReYDensityPlot[ℓ, m], {ℓ, 0, 3}, {m, 0, ℓ}], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: spherical harmonic density plots on sphere]

Comment: For the interested, [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3eSm1.png) is a version that uses a different coloring scheme...

Comment: I am wondering what do `#4 #5` refer to in your first code?

Comment: That would correspond to the parameters ϕ and θ.

Answer (score 14):

Adding the option `ColorFunctionScaling->False`, and putting directional light sources:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {Φ, 0, 2 Pi},
  ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, θ, Φ, r},
    RGBColor[Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, Φ]]^2,
      Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, θ, Φ]]^2,
      Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, θ, Φ]]^2]]),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Lighting -> ({"Directional", White, #} & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1, -1/2}, 3])]
```

gives

[image: colored sphere]

**Update**: As an alternative to playing with the `Lighting` option settings, one can enhance the color values by scaling the arguments of `RGBColor[...]` up by a factor:

```
Manipulate[ SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {Φ, 0, 2 Pi},
   ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, θ, Φ, r},
 RGBColor[ s Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, Φ]]^2,
  s Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, θ, Φ]]^2,
  s Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, θ, Φ]]^2]]),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
{{s, 10, "s"}, .5, 20, .5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Manipulate[] interface]

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a function like SphericalDensityPlot so that I can illustrate the functions?

There is [`SliceDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html)

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 Re@SphericalHarmonicY[15, 12, ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], 
   ArcTan[x, y]],
 "CenterSphere",
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
 ColorFunction -> Hue,
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]