# Using ColorData to obtain four colors

Tags: graphics, color, complex

I would like to reproduce the plot shown in fig(b) from the [link](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2014/539707/fig16/).

[image]

How can I obtain yellow, red, green and blue using the command? Let's say there are 4 roots in total. In this case roots will be {2, 1 + i,1 - i, -3 }. I'm trying plot something like in figure (b) of the above link by using the codes in a [similar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/how-to-draw-fractal-images-of-iteration-functions-on-the-riemann-sphere) post.

```
List @@@ Table[ColorData[45, k], {k, 1, Length[roots]}];
```

Thanks,
RM

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I am afraid your question is not quite clear to me at the moment. Specifically, why would you want to "obtain" the four colors when you already have them?

Comment: I'm trying to obtain something like figure (b) in https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2014/539707/fig16/ and I don't understand how command "ColorData" works...

Comment: `roots` is left undefined

Comment: Yes, but ```roots``` will be finite distinct numbers (for instance, four numbers).

Comment: Yes, but it makes a difference. For instance if `roots = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}` then `Length[roots]` is `6`. On the other hand, if `roots = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}` then `Length[roots]` is `2`. On top of that, different numbers will result in different plots.

Comment: Ok, in this case ```roots``` will be ```{2, 1 + i,1 - i, -3 }```. I'm trying plot something like in figure (b) of the above link by using the codes in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/how-to-draw-fractal-images-of-iteration-functions-on-the-riemann-sphere

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you can update the OP so other users can have easier access and you can get help more easily :-)

Comment: I presume that Syed has already do that.

Comment: The first four **colors** are just `ColorData[45] /@ Range[4]`. For the named colors use `{Yellow, Red, Green, Blue}`