# Contour plotting temperature data on a hemisphere or circle

Tags: plotting

**(edited question:)** I solved the Laplace equation(PDE) in spherical coordinates (in my problem temperature is steady and it is azimuthal(`θ`) symmetric, so my data is only a function of `r` and `φ`.)  Note that I defined the coordinates as `Spherical[r, φ, θ]`.

Now I want to make a contour plot of this data (temperature would be contoured) on the surface of a solid hemisphere(not a hollow one), but I am having problems.

This is the data that should be contoured on a hemisphere of radius `2` (`u[r, φ]`, in which: `0 < r < 2 & 0 < φ < π`)

```
K[n_] := (2 n + 1)/(n*(2^n))Integrate[10 φ LegendreP[n, Cos[φ]] Sin[φ], {φ, 0, π}] // N
u[r_, φ_] := Sum[K[n] r^n LegendreP[n, Cos[φ]], {n, 1, 8}]
```

After days probing for ans,I tried simpler contour instead of hemisphere and all of them didn't give any answer and were just running..!(except one 2D contourplot which was evaluated after an hour!) But when @WateSoyan answered my question(as below is shown) he solved the "running time" problem,he just put out the "Hue" from code, by using a pure function( `#..&`) and this accelerated the evaluation amazingly!!but I added `Rescale` function into the Hue,'coz making the domain (0...1),despite these efforts, **YET the color gradients and mesh lines are NOT ideal(as the examples I show here with 2Dcontour or with Maple)" how can the 3Dplot be corrected?**

1=> Last edition of my 3D code

```
plots = RegionPlot3D[(x <= 0) && 0 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 4, {x, -3, 
 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, #], 
PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
MaxRecursion -> 10] &@
Hue[Rescale[u[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]],
{u[2, 0], u[2, Pi]}]]
```

result=>

[image]

2Dcontour code which this one is somehow a correct answer=

```
ContourPlot[#1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 4]] & @ 
u[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcCos[y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]
```

[image]

For an analogy to the right answer,I put my code and result of it in Maple,which I'd done last week very easy!=>

```
K := (2*n+1)*(int(10*phi*LegendreP(n, x)*sin(phi), phi = 0 .. Pi))/n(10)^n
u := (rho, phi) ↦ add(K*simplify(LegendreP(n, cos(phi)))*rho^n, n = 0 .. 10)
#plotting=> #
contourplot([rho, phi, u(rho, phi+(1/2)*Pi)], rho = 0 .. c, phi = -Pi .. Pi,
coords = cylindrical, filledregions = true)
```

contour plotting in Maple in less than 30 seconds=>
[image: result of same process in Maple in 30 seconds]

Comment: if this is hard to make,if any one(instead of this) can help me for 2 plots,1.one a complete sphere of radius 10 on which u[10,phi] ((0<phi<Pi)) is contoured on surface and 2.a 2D-contourplot of the inner section of the sphere which should be contoured by u[r,phi] ((0<r<10 & 0<phi<Pi)) ,i would appreciate & thank.

Comment: Please, head to the help centre and format your code properly in the future. Did you like the post in its original version ? I doubt it. Make it easier for us as well as you to read it and when you come back at some point in the future you can pick up right where you were the previous time. Try to highlight the problems you are having, simplify the example as much as possible and show your effort. Those are the basics that will make your question attractive and will probably result in an answer.

Comment: hi dear Sektor,definitely you're right,I tried much to ask in direct and well shaped,but your edition made question much better,next time I will try more buddy,tnx ;)

Comment: Related: [Density plot on the surface of sphere](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9899/484)

Comment: You first define `u` and then suddenly plot `um`, where'd this new one come from?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. sorry,I had written `code 4` yesterday,at that moment,I had used `um` instead of `u` for defining function,now I edited it,'u' is right.

Comment: pleaaase help me,I posted it 5days ago,I tried to explain it as much as possible,I need it urgently till tomorrow,tnx in advance.

Comment: Perversely enough, saying the word "urgent" in a place like this often has the effect of making people less likely to respond. Just a tip…

Comment: Guesswhoitis ok,tnx for the tip,now whats your idea about my new edition of question?? it's almost done,except one/two obstacles

Comment: The result of `ContourPlot` in mma is similar to that in maple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `ColorFunction` may be used incorrectly,
and my edition is

```
Clear[k, u]
k[n_] := (2 n + 1)/(n*(2^n)) Integrate[10 \[CurlyPhi] LegendreP[n, 
      Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], {\[CurlyPhi], 0, \[Pi]}] // N
u[r_, \[CurlyPhi]_] := 
  Evaluate@Sum[k[n] r^n LegendreP[n, Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]], {n, 1, 8}];

plots = RegionPlot3D[(x <= 0) && 0 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 4, {x, -3, 3}, 
    {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, #],PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
    PlotPoints->100,MaxRecursion -> 10] &@
  Hue[u[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @WateSoyan,by putting out Hue function from the body of code you helped alot,but it need a "Rescale" func. in the Hue parameters because they shoould be (0-1),I made some edition on your code and put it again in my Question also with the plot of result, now there are 2problems: 1. "YET the color gradients and mesh lines are NOT ideal(as the question plots)" how can it be corrected? 2.I didn't get why putting out the "Hue" from code, by using a pure function can accelerate the evaluation?!!? can anyone explain a bit

Comment: @pccity My code works because I let `ColorFunction` know what should `u` and `k` be ! If  you replace `RegionPlot3D` with an arbitary head ,says `s`.You can see the argument of `ColorFunction` include `u` and `k`!

Comment: @pccity It ideed needs some patience to answer your messy question.

Comment: thank for your answer,I changed that with an arbitrary lettar and understood what u mean,but I'm wondering why a pure function(`#...&`)can make this difference?!? But about claiming that contourplot is correct,I knew that and I exactly had written in my edited question that the issue is correcting the 3Dcode(like the contourplot)At last I think it's not fair at all to call my question messy,I waited 5days and no one ansered me as a newbie here,so I explained it again comprehensively and percisely,finally at the 5th day U did a favor to answer,I tried to be ordered as much as possibl

Comment: @pccity Don't forget to upvote my answer in turn.I have upvoted you.

Comment: @pccity Function always keep the expression inside it unevaluate,unless you use #..&.

Comment: tnx alot dear,now i've got what U mean,about voting up it says at least I should have reputation of 15mthough I've got 6 right now! :( sorry at least now i cannot do it,whenever it become possible i will vote your answer, also if nobody answered the last problem till next week,i come and vote your answer as the solution ;)

Comment: @pccity You could ask more constructive questions to earn more.BTW,I am also a newbie here.

Comment: ok,I try more after my exams(this month)

Comment: @pccity Are you a college student?

Comment: no,a university student,mechanical engineering field

Comment: @pccity Are "college" and "university" different ?In Chinese,they share the same meaning.

Comment: i'm not english speaker too,i'm Iranian,but as I know,yes they differ,college is a level before entrance of university ;)

Comment: @pccity We are both in Asia.And you could come to China for a tour.

Comment: thanks for your affability dear,you're right,also the Iranian always would be glad to host Chinese,so glad to familiarization with you,I have to go right now,we will talk more further in chat,when I get more reputation here for chatiing ;)