# Why does one of my sliders have no effect?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

From [Density plot on the surface of sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/density-plot-on-the-surface-of-sphere)

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    RGBColor[
        Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, Φ]]^2, 
        Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, θ, Φ]]^2, 
        Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, θ, Φ]]^2
    ], 
    Disk[]
}], 
{θ, 0, 2 π}, 
{Φ, 0, 2 π}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only `Φ` expression in `SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, Φ]` is `Exp[I m Φ]`. By applying `Abs` to this expression, that turns into: `Exp[-Im[m Φ]]`. Since `m = 1` and `Φ` is `Real`, `Im[m Φ]` is `0`, and `Exp[-Im[m Φ]]` is always `1`. Thus, changing `Φ` would not do anything. The code is functioning correctly.

Comment: Ah, so I guess the fault is in the code design. Thanks.