# What is happening behind the scenes in this SphericalPlot3D function call that maps a scalar field to the surface of a sphere?

Tags: documentation

I am trying to understand what is happening in the following code [(taken from here)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9900/49271):

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {Φ, 0, 2 π}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, Φ, r}, 
         ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Cos[5 θ] + Cos[4 Φ]/2]], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

As only θ and Φ appear in the function, I thought on removing {x, y, z} from the Function parameters. But then I get a different plot. Why?

How is the function evaluated, what is happening behind the scenes?

The docs are not clear on how the arguments are passed.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html?q=SphericalPlot3D

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html?q=ColorData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments to functions correspond to the "slot" number, not the symbolic name used to represent the slot (unlike, say, Python's keyword arguments).

In

```
Function[{x, y, z, θ, Φ, r}, ...]
```

the symbol `θ` represent slot 4 and `Φ` represents slot 5.

In

```
Function[{θ, Φ, r}, ...]
```

the symbol `θ` represent slot 1 and `Φ` represents slot 2.

According to [the docs for `SphericalPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html),
the slots for `ColorFunction` are filled as follows:

- Slot 1 is passed the $x$ coordinate.
- Slot 2 is passed the $y$ coordinate.
- Slot 3 is passed the $z$ coordinate.
- Slot 4 is passed the $\theta$ coordinate.
- Slot 5 is passed the $\phi$ coordinate.
- Slot 6 is passed the $r$ coordinate.

The `ColorFunction` in the example can also be coded using [`Slot[n]` (`#n`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) and the slot numbers:

```
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Cos[5 #4] + Cos[4 #5]/2] &)
```

but the symbolic form is easier to read, imo.