# Plotting a distribution of charge into a sphere?

Tags: plotting, functions

I have defined a function $\sigma(\theta, \phi)$ (With the same angles defined by spherical coordenates) for the induced charge on a sphere with constant radius $R$, but my problem lies that I dont know how to plot this values in the surface of that sphere, any ideas in how can I do this, becuase SphericalPlot3D seems to takes functions that depend on $r$ but in doesnt take function of two varables.

[image: General plot]
[image: Spherical Plot]

Comment: Give [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9900/9490) a try

Comment: I have seen it but I dont truly understand where am I supposed to put my function?

Comment: The very first code block is quite short and `Cos[5 θ] + Cos[4 Φ]/2` fits  sigma description. p.s. do you know him: [154311](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154311/5478) Either way, without any effort and function to work with this question is most likely going to be closed. Please see [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Mauricio - the point in that answer is that you supply your function just as the `ColorFunction`, and the "function" that you supply as the first argument to `SphericalPlot3D` is just `1`

Comment: No, but that seems pretty similar to my problem

Comment: Im still having issues, becuase the general plot of my function doesnt correlate with the spherical plot that I obtained, whats the matter?

Comment: @Mauricio please focus, are we suppose to help you by looking at images without source code to work with?