# Compatibility issues with an old package

Tags: plotting, compatibility

I am trying to use the `SphericalDensityPlot3D` function that is defined here: [Spherical Density Plot 3D](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/604/#downloads).
However, when I run all the contents of the mathematica package (".m") file, I get the following errors:

> Get::noopen: Cannot open `` Utilities`FilterOptions ``.
>
> Needs::nocont: Context `` Utilities`FilterOptions `` was not created when `Needs` was evaluated.

This happens when the following cell is evaluated:

```
Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]
```

The last revision for this package is from 2001 and so I assume there are is some compatibility issue, since I am running *version 11.2*. So, does anyone know how I could fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `FilterOptions` issue has been discussed in [a number of posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=FilterOptions), you can simply modify the line

```
Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]
```

to

```
If[$VersionNumber >= 9,
   FilterOptions[a_,b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]],
   Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]]
```

This isn't the end. Though I can't figure out what exactly they are, the package has made use of some outdated features of `Graphics3D`, so to get the desired result, you need to execute

```
<< Version5`Graphics`
```

first:

[image]

But, since you're in *v11.2*, why not turn to `SliceDensityPlot3D`? You just need to transform the coordinate first:

```
expr = TransformedField[ "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
   Re[SphericalHarmonicY[4, 2, th, ph]], {r, th, ph} -> {x, y, z}];

SliceDensityPlot3D[expr, "CenterSphere", {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

BTW, for those before *v10.2*, I think the solutions in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9899/1871) are better alternatives compared to this package.

Comment: +1, nice. I did not know about this method. I removed my hack answer.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks!

Comment: @AG1123 Thanks for accepting, but actually you don't need to accept that fast, you can wait for 24 hours or even longer to see if someone will come up with a better answer :) .

Comment: I will keep that in mind in the future. :-)

Comment: This fix for FilterOptions does not seem to work in version 12. Does anyone have a new fix?

Comment: @michael Do you mean the `If[$VersionNumber >= 9,
   FilterOptions[a_,b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]],
   Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]]` is broken, or my fix for this specific package is broken? If the former, I suggest starting a new question, because this method has been used in so many answers and its failure has a big influence; if the latter, with a mobile phone it's too hard for me to test, but the `<< Version5\`Graphics\`` is more suspicious in my view.

Comment: I mean the former. When it is added to a program, the program still says "Needs::nocont: Context Utilities`FilterOptions` was not created when Needs was evaluated." I will start a new question.