# Plotting functions on surfaces

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry

So I have a 2D surface which can be parameterized by a vector $X(u1,u2)$ which I am plotting with `ParametricPlot3D[X, {u1,...}, {u2,...}]`

I have a scalar function, $f(u1,u2) \in [-fMax,fMax]$, which lives on this surface and I am trying to plot it as a heat map on the surface. I have tried this in the following way

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 X, {u1, 0, 2 Pi}, {u2, 0, 4 Pi},
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DarkRainbow",{-fMax,fMax}}][f[#1, #2] &])]
```

However this doesn't seem to work, as it gives something that is clearly wrong (doesn't match with the contour plot of the function).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! It would help, if you would extend (by editing) the description of the problem a little bit. Please give a defintiion of `f` and `X` add the output you get, and if possible, a example of the output you would like to have. Note, that you can qutie easily paste images to the post.

Comment: Is this similar to what you need? [Density plot on the surface of sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/density-plot-on-the-surface-of-sphere)

Comment: If you want to supply the parameterization parameters to the color function, you should use the last two slots: `f[#4, #5] &`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is in the wrong place in `ColorFunction` option setting. You need to move it outside `ColorFunction[...]` and add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
X = {(2 + Cos[u2]) Cos[u1], (2 + Cos[u2]) Sin[u1], Sin[u2]};
f = N@10 Sin[# + #2] &;
fMax = 10;
ParametricPlot3D[X, {u1, 0, 2 Pi}, {u2, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {-fMax, fMax}}][f[#1, #2]] &)]
```

[image]