Using ColourFunction in SphericalPlot3D
I have a function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ that I'm restricting to $\mathbb{S}^2$ . For example, let $F(x,y,z)=x+y+z$.
 F[{x_, y_, z_}] := x + y + z;
When I plot $F$ on $\mathbb{S}^2$, projected onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ using Plot3D, I can easily implement ColorFunction to give colours corresponding to the value of $F$.
Plot3D[F[{Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
   Cos[\[Theta]]}], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{\[Theta], \[Phi], z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Theta]", "\[Phi]", "F"}] 



However, I want to use SphericalPlot3D to see what this function looks like on $\mathbb{S}^2$. The issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to define the ColorFunction such that it will give colours corresponding to the above plot. The closest I have come to is:
SphericalPlot3D[
 1 + F[{Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
    Cos[\[Theta]]}], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function
   [{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][F[{x, y, z}]]], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}}], 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]]


This is obviously not giving the same result as the Plot3D colour scheme. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?
P.S. In reality $F$ will need to be any function on $\mathbb{R}^3$, including nonlinear ones so hopefully the fix will work in general!

You just need SliceDensityPlot3D

This question is similar to: Density plot on the surface of sphere. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To be more specific, check https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124080/1871

Hi @xzczd, thanks for the suggestion. I've just edited the question there to hopefully demonstrate how it's different. I believe SliceDensityPlot3D will fail to work if I cannot express the surface as an implicit equation. For example, if I'm plotting $1+F$ on SphericalPlot3D, I'd like to be able to see the "height" on the plot as well as the colours.

Hmm... Then I'd argue this can be easily found in the document. (Just see the first 2 examples under Options -> ColorFunction section of document of SphericalPlot3D. ) Anyway, it's no longer a duplicate of suggested post, duplicate vote retracted.

Use ColorData["Rainbow"][r] instead of  ColorData["Rainbow"][F[{x, y, z}]].
SphericalPlot3D[
 F[{Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
   Cos[\[Theta]]}], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function
   [{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, ColorData["Rainbow"][r]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}}], 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8], PlotPoints -> 100]




Thank you very much! I can't believe I missed this
