# How to add texture to solid Graphics3D object such as cylinder?

Tags: graphics3d, textures

I'd like to add texture to a `Cylinder` inside `Graphics3D`. I can't see how to use `FaceForm` and tell it to use `Texture`. The problem is `Texture` needs `TextureCoordinateFunction`.

I saw few solutions, but many use `ParametricPlot3D`, which I could use, but I need a solid `Cylinder`, so I would have to do the top/bottom faces manually. For example, using the solution in [Applying an ArrayPlot as a texture to the surface of a cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17084/applying-an-arrayplot-as-a-texture-to-the-surface-of-a-cylinder)  I could do

```
mplt = MatrixPlot[Table[Sin[x y/100], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> 0, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0];
p = ParametricPlot3D[{ Cos[theta], Sin[theta], rho}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, {rho, 0, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 30], Texture[mplt]], 
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #3} &), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, TextureCoordinateScaling -> True];

Graphics3D[First@p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But what I want is to add texture to outside surface of

```
  Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 1], Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is solution here for 2D objects [How to texturize a Disk/Circle/Rectangle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7657/how-to-texturize-a-disk-circle-rectangle)  since one can find the `VertexTextureCoordinates` are easy to do for these.

I think what is needed here is to tell `FaceForm` to use `Texture`? but do not know how to go about this. Version 9.01

Comment: I'd do `Graphics3D[{First@p, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, .99]}, 
 Axes -> True]`

Comment: @Kuba I actually thought about this, but the top/bottom faces will be different, and more important, I am not sure it is efficient, since I am rendering a 3D object (cylinder) in addition to the texture itself. I am trying to see if I can make a circle with same texture and add these to the ParametricPlot3D to build the cylinder manually. If all else fails, will use what you suggested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, I don't think it's possible to use `Texture` directly with the built-in primitives such as `Sphere` and `Cylinder`. See also [Texture mapping and resizing a sphere primitive in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52/245).

So you have to write your own replacement for those primitives. Since you specifically mentioned the `Cylinder`, I added the ability to handle `Texture` to my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51573/245). There, I already had added `VertexNormals` to give the smooth appearance that the `Cylinder` primitive has. Here, I inserted the `VertexTextureCoordinates` option into all the polygons making up the sides of my custom cylinder. The result is the following:

```
ClearAll[prism];
prism[pts_List, h_] := 
 Module[{bottoms, tops, surfacePoints, sidePoints, n}, 
  surfacePoints = 
   Table[Map[PadRight[#, 3, height] &, pts], {height, {0, h}}];
  {bottoms, tops} = {Most[#], Rest[#]} &@surfacePoints;
  sidePoints = 
   Flatten[{bottoms, RotateLeft[bottoms, {0, 1}], 
     RotateLeft[tops, {0, 1}], tops}, {{2, 3}, {1}}];
  n = Length[sidePoints];
  MapThread[
   Polygon[#1, VertexNormals -> (#1 - #2), 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> #3] &, {
    Join[sidePoints, surfacePoints], 
    Join[Map[{0, 0, 1} # &, sidePoints, {2}], 
     Map[({1, 1, 0} # - {0, 0, h/2}) &, surfacePoints, {2}]
     ],
    Join[
     Table[{{i/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 1}, {i/n, 1}}, {i, 
       0, n - 1}],
     Table[None, {Length[surfacePoints]}]]
    }
   ]]

Clear[cyl];
cyl[{pt1_, pt2_}, r_: 1, n_: 90] := 
 Module[{circle = 
    r Table[{Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], Pi/n, 2 Pi, Pi/n}], 
   h = EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]}, 
  GeometricTransformation[prism[circle, h], 
   Composition[TranslationTransform[pt1], 
    Quiet[Check[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1.}, pt2 - pt1}], 
      Identity]]]]]
```

The actual work is done in `prism`, and the compatibility with `Cylinder` is provided by the wrapper `cyl`. Here is a test:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Graphics3D[{Texture[img], EdgeForm[], 
  cyl[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 Pi}}, 1]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: lenaTube]

To get the smoothness of the surface, it's good to set the proper `VertexNormals` as I do in the `prism` function.

**Edit**

As an extension of this answer, you can also add textures to the base and top of the cylinder. That's done in my answer to the question [How can this texture be inserted in the beginning and the end of cylinder?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61332/245).