# How can this texture be inserted in the beginning and the end of cylinder?

Tags: plotting

```
ClearAll[prism];
prism[pts_List, h_] := 
Module[{bottoms, tops, surfacePoints, sidePoints, n}, 
surfacePoints = 
Table[Map[PadRight[#, 3, height] &, pts], {height, {0, h}}];
{bottoms, tops} = {Most[#], Rest[#]} &@surfacePoints;
sidePoints = 
Flatten[{bottoms, RotateLeft[bottoms, {0, 1}], 
RotateLeft[tops, {0, 1}], tops}, {{2, 3}, {1}}];
n = Length[sidePoints];
MapThread[
Polygon[#1, VertexNormals -> (#1 - #2), 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> #3] &, {Join[sidePoints, 
surfacePoints], 
Join[Map[{0, 0, 1} # &, sidePoints, {2}], 
 Map[({1, 1, 0} # + {0, 0, h/2}) &, surfacePoints, {2}]], 
Join[Table[{{i/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 1}, {i/n, 
    1}}, {i, 0, n - 1}], Table[None, {Length[surfacePoints]}]]}]]
Clear[cyl];
cyl[{pt1_, pt2_}, r_: 1, n_: 90] := 
Module[{circle = 
r Table[{Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], Pi/n, 2 Pi, Pi/n}], 
h = EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]}, 
GeometricTransformation[prism[circle, h], 
Composition[TranslationTransform[pt1], 
Quiet[Check[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1.}, pt2 - pt1}], 
  Identity]]]]]
Graphics3D[{Texture[], EdgeForm[], cyl[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 Pi}}, 1]}, Boxed -> True, 
Axes -> True]
```

I want to inserted in the beginning and the end of cylinder texture but it didint work:
[image]

Comment: It would be nice of you to explain better your questions, instead of dumping a page of code and a one-line request, as you are doing now AND you did in your previous question.

Comment: You got this code from [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52336/245). It would have been better to include a link to that in your question, because nobody likes to see a bunch of code without explanation and context. So by beginning and end you mean the bottom and top faces of the cylinder?

Comment: Yes because I want to see like a wood beam, thanks and sorry...

Answer (score 6):

In principle, if you already have the cylinder and just want to add textured caps, you can **add** those with two separate `Polygon` commands. However, the code you are using can also be modified to include the texture in the output directly.

You copied the code from [my answer to a question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52336/245) where only textured *sides* were desired. This was achieved by explicitly setting the `VertexTextureCoordinates` to `None` for the top and bottom polygons, contained in the variable `surfacepoints`. All that is needed is to replace `None` by the appropriate values, and any `texture` will also show up on those polygons.

Here I made that change. The function `cyl` hasn't been modified, I'm only including it for completeness. The only change is at the end of `prism`, the last `Table` containing `None` has been replaced by `{#, #} &[Rescale[pts, {-h, h}/2]]`. The resulting list is then fed into `MapThread` which assembles the oolygons from their vertices. The `Rescale` is added here to make sure that the image appears with a comparable magnification on all sides of the cylinder. This is determined from the relative size of the end caps versus the height `h` of the cylinder.

```
cyl[{pt1_, pt2_}, r_: 1, n_: 90] := Module[{
   circle = 
    r Table[{Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, Pi/n, 2 Pi, Pi/n}], 
   h = EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]
   },
  GeometricTransformation[prism[circle, h], 
   Composition[TranslationTransform[pt1], 
    Quiet[Check[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1.}, pt2 - pt1}], Identity]]]
   ]
  ]

prism[pts_List, h_] := 
 Module[{bottoms, tops, surfacePoints, sidePoints, n}, 
  surfacePoints = Table[
    Map[PadRight[#, 3, height] &, pts], {height, {0, h}}
    ];
  {bottoms, tops} = {Most[#], Rest[#]} &@surfacePoints;
  sidePoints = 
   Flatten[{bottoms, RotateLeft[bottoms, {0, 1}], 
     RotateLeft[tops, {0, 1}], tops}, {{2, 3}, {1}}];
  n = Length[sidePoints];
  MapThread[
   Polygon[#1, VertexNormals -> (#1 - #2), 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> #3] &,
   {
    Join[sidePoints, surfacePoints],
    Join[
     Map[{0, 0, 1} # &, sidePoints, {2}], 
     Map[({1, 1, 0} # - {0, 0, h/2}) &, surfacePoints, {2}]
     ],
    Join[
     Table[
      {{i/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 1}, {i/n, 1}}, {i, 0, 
       n - 1}
      ],
     {#, #} &[Rescale[pts, {-h, h}/2]]
     ]
    }
   ]
  ]

img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Graphics3D[{Texture[img], EdgeForm[], 
  cyl[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 Pi}}, 1]}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image: cyl]

Comment: +1 Weil ich Lena so mag: Versuchungen sollte man nachgeben. Wer weiß, ob sie wiederkommen?