# How do I draw a polygon defined by a list of data points?

Tags: graphics3d

I am attempting to make a 3D model of a device defined by a list of {x,y,z} points, digitized from a 2D image. The z coordinate is defined in mma.

What I tried so far:

```
area = {{0, 452.45658}, {414.75187, 601.63611}, {506.55465, 
    696.71757}, {832.78241, 686.88155}, {936.06054, 
    739.34029}, {1103.27276, 719.66826}, {1155.73149, 
    726.2256}, {1218.02624, 701.63557}, {1281.96032, 
    686.88155}, {1618.02409, 677.04554}, {1740.97425, 
    588.52143}, {2040.97264, 465.57127}, {2077.90455, 
    459.01393}, {2077.90455, 0}, {1581.95871, 0}, {1475.40191, 
    203.2776}, {1301.63235, 608.19345}, {1180.32152, 
    649.17684}, {1163.92817, 667.20953}, {1132.7808, 
    667.20953}, {1073.76472, 660.65219}, {944.25722, 
    673.76687}, {899.99516, 644.25883}, {837.70042, 
    627.86548}, {809.83171, 601.63611}, {809.83171, 
    578.68541}, {609.83279, 111.47481}, {560.65272, 0}, {0, 0}};

area1 = MapThread[Append, {area, ConstantArray[0, Length[area]]}];

area2 = MapThread[Append, {area, ConstantArray[200, Length[area]]}];

Show[Graphics3D[Polygon[area1]], Graphics3D[Polygon[area2]]]

(*This shows top and bottom faces of desired shape, but I want the sides filled in*)

total = Join[area1, area2];

Graphics3D[Polygon[total]]

(*This makes a 3D polygon, but the points are not ordered correctly*)

Graphics3D[
 Polygon[total[[
   FindShortestTour[total] // Flatten // Delete[#, {{1}, {-1}}] &]]]]

(*This reorders the points, but not in the way I want. I don't think there is a way to simply reorder the points in the right way.*)
```

Comment: The ordering problem may be solved using `ListCurvePathPlot`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Based on the description, it seems the starting point was a binary image. In that case, this could be a duplicate of, or at least closely related to, [How to extrude a 3D image from a binary 2D image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6206/245)

Comment: very good mathematica in programs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
topbottom = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.7], Polygon /@ {area1, area2}}];

sides = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.7], 
    Polygon[Partition[Join @@ Transpose[{Join[area1, {First@area1}], 
            Join[area2, {First@area2}]}], 3, 1]]}];

Show[topbottom, sides, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, put everything in a single `Graphics3D`:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.7], Polygon /@ {area1, area2}, EdgeForm[], 
  Polygon[Partition[Join @@ Transpose[{Join[area1, {First@area1}], 
       Join[area2, {First@area2}]}], 3, 1]]}, ImageSize -> 600]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: Hi All, Thanks kguler, virgil, and others. I used virgil's functionization of kguler's solution, I have numerous funny shapes to "extrude."

Answer (score 7):

It think it is nice to know that with latest Computational Geometry it is very simple - just a an orthogonal [RegionProduct](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct.html).

```
R2 = MeshRegion[area, Polygon[Range[Length[area]]]];
R3 = RegionProduct[R2, Line[{{0.}, {500.}}]];
```

Now you can for example:

```
RegionMeasure[R3]
```

or

```
DiscretizeRegion[R3]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice (+1).  I can't believe I didn't think of this. Note that `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionProduct[Polygon[area], Line[{{0.}, {500.}}]]]` takes about 1/10 the memory.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks,we are aware, good things are on the way ;)

Answer (score 4):

I found out that this is basically the same as @kguler's answer, but I want to mention that this can be easily functionized. Borrowing from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80512/extruding-a-wierd-2d-shape-to-make-a-prismatic-3d-shape/80615#80615), we can define something similar:

```
Options[Extrude] = Join[
   Options[Graphics3D], {Closed -> True, Capped -> True, Color -> Orange}];

Extrude[points_, {zmin_, zmax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{pts, tube, caps},
   If[OptionValue[Closed], pts = points~Join~{First@points}];
   tube = Polygon[
     Partition[
      Join @@ Transpose[points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #} & /@ {zmin, zmax}], 3, 1]];
   If[OptionValue[Closed] && OptionValue[Capped], 
    caps = Polygon[points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #}] & /@ {zmin, zmax};
    tube = Flatten@{tube, caps}, 
    tube = {tube}];
   Graphics3D[Flatten@{EdgeForm[None], OptionValue[Color], #} & /@ tube, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics3D]]]
  ];
```

Then, apply it to the points `area` thusly:

```
Extrude[area, {0, 200}, Color -> Red]
```

[image: extrude]

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use the function `prism` from my answer to [How can this texture be inserted in the beginning and the end of cylinder?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61332/245).

The advantage is that it also allows you to add textures (optionally), and has vertex normals built in so that the shape appears *smooth*. Here it is just for fun:

```
l = {{"Directional", Red, ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
   {"Directional", Green, ImageScaled[{-2, 2, 2}]},
   {"Directional", Blue, ImageScaled[{-2, -2, 2}]}};

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], prism[area, 500]}, 
 Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, Lighting -> l, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image: shape]

I set the shape to have no edges, so as to emphasize the smoothness. But if you *want* to see the striations on the side walls, just omit `EdgeForm[]` above. The result will then be this:

[image: edges]

**Edit**

The original version of the function `prism` determined vertex normals based on the assumption that the shape is really a cylinder, or at least convex. That doesn't give very good estimates of all the appropriate vertex normals in this case, so it prompted me to look for a more accurate way of determining a set of vertex normals that still do the job of smoothly interpolating between adjacent face normals.

Here is what I came up with:

```
prism[pts_List, h_] := 
 Module[{bottoms, tops, surfacePoints, sidePoints, n}, 
  surfacePoints = 
   Table[Map[PadRight[#, 3, height] &, pts], {height, {0, h}}];
  {bottoms, tops} = {Most[#], Rest[#]} &@surfacePoints;
  sidePoints = 
   Flatten[{bottoms, RotateLeft[bottoms, {0, 1}], 
     RotateLeft[tops, {0, 1}], tops}, {{2, 3}, {1}}];
  n = Length[sidePoints];
  MapThread[Polygon[#1,
     VertexNormals -> #2,
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> #3] &, {Join[sidePoints, 
     surfacePoints], 
    Join[normals[sidePoints], 
     Map[({0, 0, h/2}) &, surfacePoints, {2}]], 
    Join[Table[{{i/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 1}, {i/n, 
        1}}, {i, 0, n - 1}], {#, #} &[Rescale[pts, {-h, h}/2]]]}]]

normals[s_] := Module[{faceN, faceLeft, faceRight},
  faceN = Map[Cross @@ Differences[#[[1 ;; 3]]] &, s];
  faceLeft = RotateLeft[faceN];
  faceRight = RotateRight[faceN];
  MapThread[{#1 + #2, #1 + #3, #1 + #3, #1 + #2} &, {faceN, faceRight,
     faceLeft}]
  ]

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], 
   GeometricTransformation[prism[area, 500],
    Composition[
     RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}], 
     TranslationTransform[{-1000, -500, 0}]]]}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600, Lighting -> l, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1200, 1200}, {-1200, 1200}, {-10, 510}}], {θ,
   0, 2 Pi}
 ]
```

[image: vertexnormals]

In the `VertexNormals` option, `prism` now calls the function `normals` which takes a list of polygon face quads and calculates for each vertex what the normals of adjacent faces are. Then it just adds those normals as a way to produce an interpolating average that makes the side walls look smooth. For the top and bottom of the prism, I chose a constant vertical normal (it doesn't even change direction because that is taken care of by the fact that the polygon orientation is opposite on top and bottom).

Having a smooth side wall may or may not be what the question is after - but since this is the main point of my answer, I decided to expand on the discussion of `VertexNormals` for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Another way with rectangular polygons on the sides:

```
bottom = PadRight[area, {Automatic, 3}, 0];
top = PadRight[area, {Automatic, 3}, 400];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.7], EdgeForm[],
  Polygon[Join[
    {bottom, top},
    Join[
     Partition[bottom, 2, 1, 1],
     RotateLeft@Reverse@Partition[top // Reverse, 2, 1, 1],
     2]
    ]]
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
area = {{0, 452.45658}, {414.75187, 601.63611}, {506.55465, 
    696.71757}, {832.78241, 686.88155}, {936.06054, 
    739.34029}, {1103.27276, 719.66826}, {1155.73149, 
    726.2256}, {1218.02624, 701.63557}, {1281.96032, 
    686.88155}, {1618.02409, 677.04554}, {1740.97425, 
    588.52143}, {2040.97264, 465.57127}, {2077.90455, 
    459.01393}, {2077.90455, 0}, {1581.95871, 0}, {1475.40191, 
    203.2776}, {1301.63235, 608.19345}, {1180.32152, 
    649.17684}, {1163.92817, 667.20953}, {1132.7808, 
    667.20953}, {1073.76472, 660.65219}, {944.25722, 
    673.76687}, {899.99516, 644.25883}, {837.70042, 
    627.86548}, {809.83171, 601.63611}, {809.83171, 
    578.68541}, {609.83279, 111.47481}, {560.65272, 0}, {0, 0}};
area3D = Table[{area[[i, 1]], area[[i, 2]], j}, 
    {i, Length[area]}, {j, 0, 500, 30}];

   Graphics3D[{Line /@ area3D, Line /@ Transpose[area3D], 
   Polygon[Transpose[area3D]]}]
```

[image]