# Phase portrait on a cylinder

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d

It is very nice and very easy to make a sketch of a [phase portrait](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PhasePortrait.html) with `StreamPlot`. For example, for the classical pendulum, defined by

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dot x&=&y,\\
\dot y&=&-\sin x,
\end{eqnarray*}

The code

```
StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Frame -> None, StreamPoints -> Fine, AspectRatio -> 0.8,
  Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{0, 0}, {\[Pi], 0}, {-\[Pi], 0}}]}]
```

produces

[image]

Now to the question. The actual phase space for the pendulum is not the plane $\mathbf R^2$, but the cylinder $\mathbf S^1\times \mathbf R$, and the pendulum of course has only two equilibria, one at $(0,0)$ and another one at $(\pi,0)$. Actually two points in the graph, the left and the right ones, are the same equilibrium.

Question: How in *Mathematica* I can efficiently plot my phase portrait on a cylinder, such that I have only two equilibria, and I could see through the whole cylinder (I found examples on the site how to put a texture on a cylinder, but cannot figure out how to make it transparent).

Comment: This may be interesting [Basins of Attraction](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/basins-of-attraction).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
plot = StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -3, 3},  Frame -> None,  
          Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{0, 0}, {π, 0}, {-π, 0}}]}, 
          StreamPoints -> Fine,  AspectRatio -> 0.8]
```

Try this:

```
First[Normal@plot] /.  a_Arrow :> (
                        a /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {Cos[x], Sin[x], y}
                                  ) // Graphics3D
```

[image]

You can add `Cylinder` if you want:

```
Show[ %, 
      Graphics3D@{Opacity@.7, LightBlue, Cylinder[{{0, 0, -3}, {0, 0, 3}}]}
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I think it looks better with the cylinder added, though...

Comment: @Jens You are right, I just wanted to fulfill question about transparency :)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 19):

You could use an image representation of the plot and map it onto the modified cylinder that I defined in [the answer linked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52336/245).

Just copy the definition of `cyl` from that answer, which includes the ability to add textures as follows:

```
img = Image@StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3},
    Frame -> None,
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-3, 3}}, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, 
      Point[{{0, 0}, {Pi, 0}, {-Pi, 0}}]}, StreamPoints -> Fine,
     AspectRatio -> 0.8, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0,
    ImageSize -> 800];

Graphics3D[{Texture[img], EdgeForm[], 
  cyl[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 Pi}}, 1]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: cyl]

The resolution is controlled by the options of `Image` or by the `ImageSize` options in `StreamPlot`.

I also added the `PlotRange` to the original plot to suppress the plot range padding.

**Edit**

To make the whole thing transparent, you can use the same approach provided that the image has an alpha channel with transparent background:

```
img = Rasterize[
   StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-3, 3}}, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, 
      Point[{{0, 0}, {Pi, 0}, {-Pi, 0}}]}, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
    AspectRatio -> 0.8, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, 
    ImageSize -> 500], Background -> None, ImageResolution -> 300
   ];

Graphics3D[{Texture[ImageData@img], EdgeForm[], 
  cyl[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 Pi}}, 1]}, Boxed -> False, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: trasnp]

Here I used `Rasterize` because it permits a `Background -> None` option. Also, I used `ImageResolution` in combination with the `ImageSize` specification of the `StreamPlot` to make sure that the `Point`s from the `Epilog` in the original plot are properly visible.

To combine transparency with a cylinder "backbone" for better visibility, you could do it like this:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[ImageData@img], EdgeForm[], 
  cyl[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 Pi}}, 1], 
  FaceForm[Directive[Opacity[.5], Orange]], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, -.01}, {0, 0, 2 Pi + .01}}, .99]}, Boxed -> False, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: backbone]

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question ("I found examples on the site how to put a texture on a cylinder, but cannot figure out how to make it transparent")?

Comment: One could add an alpha channel: `img2 = Image[ImageData[img] /. {{1., 1., 1.} -> {1., 1., 1., 0.5}, {r_, g_, b_} :> {r, g, b, 1.}}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]`.  (Top & bottom stay solid, though.)  But I agree with your other comment.  The way it is is easier to see.