# Mapping two textures over a 3D surface

Tags: plotting, textures

I would like to show the current distribution in a thin cylinder in 3D. The figure below shows the open cylinder.

[image: open cylinder]

I am trying to use that figure as a texture in a 3D plot inspired by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13668/49271).

```
scalarField[r_, \[Phi]_, z_] := 
  1/Pi*(z + 2*Sum[Sinh[n*z]/Cosh[n*3]/n*Cos[n*\[Phi]], {n, 1, 33}]);
contourTexture = 
  ContourPlot[
   scalarField[1, \[Phi], z], {z, \[Phi]} \[Element] 
    Rectangle[{-3, -Pi}, {3, Pi}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> False];
streamTexture = 
  StreamPlot[{-D[scalarField[1, \[Phi], z], z], -D[
      scalarField[1, \[Phi], z], \[Phi]]}, {z, \[Phi]} \[Element] 
    Rectangle[{-3, -Pi}, {3, Pi}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   Evaluated -> True, Frame -> False, StreamStyle -> Black];
rev = RevolutionPlot3D[{1, t}, {t, -3, 3}, 
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), 
   PlotStyle -> Texture[contourTexture + streamTexture]];
Show[rev]
```

The output I am getting is:

[image: output]

Two points I don't know:

1. What to pass as `TextureCoordinateFunction`
2. if the calling `PlotStyle -> Texture[contourTexture +
   streamTexture]` is correct

I have also seen [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65401/mapping-streamplot-onto-spherical-surfaces), but I can't figure out how to adapt it.

Comment: related: [Phase portrait on a cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64407/5478)

Comment: Is this the result you are after? `RevolutionPlot3D[{1, t}, {t, -3, 3}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &), 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Texture[
    Show[contourTexture, streamTexture, PlotRangePadding -> None]], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]`

Comment: @Kuba that's exactly what I was after. Could you post an answer and, while at it, explain what `#4` and `#5` are in `TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)`?

Comment: See documentation details and options for TextureCoordinateFunction. Also see: [17084](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17084/5478)