# Fine-tuning stereographic stream plots

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, projection

I would like to present Möbius transformations on the Riemann sphere. Having found the masterpiece answers to [Mapping StreamPlot onto spherical surfaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65401/35000), I am trying to adapt it to my case (those ones are about something slightly different - when the vector field is periodic to begin with).

This almost works, except I cannot regulate the density; it is either concentrated at the north pole, or features a bald spot around it:

```
Graphics3D[{StreamPlot[
 ReIm[(1 + I) (x + I y)], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}][[1]] /. 
  Arrow[z_] :> 
   Arrow[z /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {2 x, 2 y, x^2 + y^2 - 1}/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)], 
Opacity[.5], Sphere[]}, ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> False]
```

results in

[image: bald spot]

while

```
Graphics3D[{StreamPlot[
 ReIm[(1 + I) (x + I y)], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}][[1]] /. 
  Arrow[z_] :> 
   Arrow[z /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {2 x, 2 y, x^2 + y^2 - 1}/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)], 
Opacity[.5], Sphere[]}, ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> False]
```

(i. e. changing 3 to 100) leaves me with

[image: concentrated]

What would be the correct way to do it?

**Later**

Have tried to force stream points uniformly along several small concentric circles around origin. It is better but still messy, don't even know why...

```
Graphics3D[{StreamPlot[
 ReIm[(1 + 2 I) (x + I y)], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
 StreamPoints -> {
   Flatten[Table[2^-c {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/3}, {c, .2, .8, .2}], 1],
   500, 200}][[1]] /. 
  Arrow[z_] :> Arrow[z /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {2 x, 2 y, x^2 + y^2 - 1}/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)], 
Opacity[.5], Sphere[]}, ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: "features a bald spot around it" - if the original `StreamPlot[]` is over a small domain (e.g. `{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}` in the first example), then it's no surprise you don't have much arrows near the point at infinity.

Comment: @J.M. Yes it is probably that - but when I increase the domain it does all squeeze at the north pole

Comment: Hmm, may I suggest using spherical coordinates at the outset? `StreamPlot[ReIm[(1 + I) (Cot[ϕ/2] Exp[I θ])], {θ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕ, 0, π}]`

Comment: @J.M. OK then how to move it to the sphere??

Comment: I am trying to combine your suggestion with the formula from the linked answers but get something totally different

Answer (score 2):

As noted, one should already use the Riemann sphere representation of a complex number at the outset:

```
sp = First[StreamPlot[{{-Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {-Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}}.
                      ReIm[(1 + I) (Cot[ϕ/2] Exp[I θ])], {θ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕ, 0, π}]];

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], Sphere[]}, 
            sp /. Arrow[v_?MatrixQ] :> 
            Arrow[Tube[Function[{θ, ϕ}, {Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[ϕ]}] @@@ v]]}, 
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: stream plot over the Riemann sphere]

Comment: Thanks - but this is not the plot of the original transformation!

Comment: Hmm, something's weird, even though the transformations check out. I'll look into it later.

Comment: Must go like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_PLp_9jOiOP8/SXYvMd4vWqI/AAAAAAAAAWI/M0j7NZ7wCCo/s1600/escher+loxodrome.jpg)

Comment: Assuming I didn't mess up my Jacobians and everything, I think this should be correct now.

Comment: Sorry I am still not sure it is entirely correct. Your lines seem to approach the pole along meridians, while in fact they must wind around tangentially. In other words, locally at the pole one must see logarithmic rather than archimedean spirals.

Comment: Maybe I can write up how I derived the Jacobian later, and you might be able to figure what wrong assumptions I made?

Comment: Would be good if you can find time for that. I am trying to understand what's going on, but keep failing.