# Mapping Streamplot into graphics without arrows

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

This question follows from the example below

[Mapping StreamPlot onto spherical surfaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65401/mapping-streamplot-onto-spherical-surfaces)

When I'm trying to remove the arrows I cannot get the 3d graphics:

```
sp = StreamPlot[{Cot[θ] Cos[ϕ], -Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, -π, π}, {θ, 0, π},  
   StreamColorFunction -> Hue, 
   StreamScale -> None, ImageSize -> 200];

sp3d = Graphics3D[
   sp[[1]] /. 
    Arrow[z_] :> 
     Arrow[z /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {Cos[x] Sin[y], Sin[y] Sin[x], 
         Cos[y]}], ImageSize -> 200];
Row[{sp, sp3d}, Spacer[5]]
```

The result is below. Any idea how to get the 3d graphics without the arrows?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also post-process the graphics objects `sp` and `sp3d` from the accepted answer in the [the linked q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65407/125) (1) to change `Arrow`s to `Line`s or (2) to change the `Arrowheads` directive to `Arrowheads[0]`:

```
sp = StreamPlot[{Cot[θ] Cos[ϕ], -Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, - π, π}, {θ, 0, π}, 
  StreamColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 200];
sp3d = Graphics3D[sp[[1]] /.  Arrow[z_] :>  
     Arrow[z /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {Cos[x] Sin[y], Sin[y] Sin[x], Cos[y]}], 
  ImageSize -> 200];

Row[{sp, sp3d} /. Arrow -> Line, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{sp, sp3d} /. Arrowheads[_] :> Arrowheads[0], Spacer[5]]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 4):

The `sp` output includes a [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex), so the arguments of the primitives are indices into the [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex) and not coordinates. Also, your [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot) uses [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line) primitives instead of [`Arrow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow) primitives. So, a corrected version would be:

```
Graphics3D[
    ReplaceAll[
        Normal[sp][[1]],
        Line[z_]:>Line[z/.{x_Real,y_Real}:>{Cos[x] Sin[y],Sin[y] Sin[x],Cos[y]}]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Note that [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) modifies the colors, so an alternative is to transform the [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex):

```
Graphics3D[
    ReplaceAll[
        sp[[1]],
        {x_Real,y_Real}:>{Cos[x] Sin[y],Sin[y] Sin[x],Cos[y]}
    ],
    ImageSize->400
]
```

[image]

The latter method is identical to @Jason's now deleted answer.