Plotting a vector field on a cylinder
Assume a parametric equation for a cylinder
$$\mathrm{cyl} (\theta, z) = (r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta,z)$$
and a vector field given by
$$\mathrm{vecField} (\theta, z)=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{r}\partial_\theta \mathrm{cyl} + \cos(\alpha)\partial_z \mathrm{cyl},$$
where $\partial_\theta \mathrm{cyl},\partial_z \mathrm{cyl}$ are the tangent vectors of the cylindrical surface which can be calculated as $(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, respectively. The equation for the vector field becomes
$$\mathrm{vecField} (\theta, z)=(-\sin\theta \sin(\alpha)/r, \cos\theta \sin(\alpha)/r, \cos(\alpha))$$
where $\alpha = \pi/3$.
How can one plot the vector field on the cylindrical surface with Mathematica?

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/phase-portrait-on-a-cylinder

First define the cylinder:
r = 1;
pos[th_, z_] :=  {r  Cos[th], r  Sin[th], z};

Then define both base vectors and the vectors of the vector field:
eth[th_, z_] := {-Sin[th], Cos[th], 0};
ez = {0, 0, 1};

vecs = Table[
   Arrow[{pos[th, z], 
     pos[th, z] + 0.4 (Sin[th]/r  eth[th, z] + Cos[th]  ez)}], {z, 0, 
    2, 0.5}, {th, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}];

Finally, draw the graphics:
Graphics3D[{vecs, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}]}]



Clear[x, y, r];
field = {-Sin[θ] Sin[α]/r, Cos[θ] Sin[α]/r, Cos[α]};
field2 = TransformedField["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", 
  field, {r, θ, z} -> {x, y, zz}];

α = π/3; r = 1;
VectorPlot3D[field2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic, 
 VectorPoints -> 
  Flatten[Table[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], z}, {θ, 0, 2 π, π/16}, {z, -1, 1, .1}], 1]]


Updated
Alternatively,
SliceVectorPlot3D[field2, 
 x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]


