# Better way to visualize cylinder puzzle solution

Tags: manipulate, animation, visualization

[image]

The above puzzle has been a recent source of amusement in my clique.

I decided to provide a visualization to motivate solution ([here](https://ubpdqnmathematica.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/cp1.gif?w=595)):

My code:

```
s[x_] := Piecewise[{{4 Mod[x, 3]/3, 
    EvenQ[Quotient[x, 3]]}, {4 Mod[x, 3]/3, True}}]
plot = Plot[s[x], {x, 0, 12}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed, 
  Epilog -> {{Green, Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0.1}, {3, 0.1}}], Text["3 cm", {1.5, 0.2}]}, {Purple, 
     Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], Text["4 cm", {3.7, 2}], 
     Arrow[{{3.2, 0}, {3.2, 4}}], Text["3 cm", {1.5, 0.2}]}, {Orange, 
     Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], Arrow[{{-0.2, 0}, {2.8, 4}}], 
     Text["5 cm", {1, 2.2}]}}, Frame -> True, 
  Background -> LightYellow, ImageSize -> 400];
r = 2./Pi;
tf[u_, v_, n_] := {u, n Cos[Pi r  v/(2 n)], n Sin[ Pi r v /(2 n)]};
dat = Table[{j, s[j]}, {j, 0, 2.9, 0.1}]~Join~
   Table[{j, s[j]}, {j, 3, 5.9, 0.1}]~Join~
   Table[{j, s[j]}, {j, 6, 8.9, 0.1}]~Join~
   Table[{j, s[j]}, {j, 9, 11.9, 0.1}];
```

culminating in:

```
Manipulate[
 Panel[Column[{Show[
     ParametricPlot3D[{u, a Cos[Pi r v/(2 a)] - a, 
       a Sin[Pi r v/(2 a)]}, {u, 0, 12}, {v, 0, 4}, Mesh -> False, 
      BoundaryStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 
     Graphics3D[{Blue, Thick, 
       Line /@ Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]] - a, #[[
            3]]} &, (tf[#1, #2, a] & @@@ # & /@ 
           Partition[dat, 10]), {2}]}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
     Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Background -> Black, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, ImageSize -> 400], 
    plot}]], {a, r, 10}]
```

This does achieve the aim (I think). However, I would value correction or alternatives that improve things such as:

- better ways to draw lines and curl plane into cylinder
- smoother ways to deal with/speed flatter phase (can obviously vary step size)
- using `Tube` for rope and texturing
- combining the plot which has annotations referring to puzzle dimensions on the 3D plot (obviously could use texture).

Of course, if and when I get time to play I will, but I wondered whether this would be a fun contemplation for someone here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you want the animation to have explanatory content, I thought it might be best to incorporate the explanatory 2D diagram into the 3D scene.

So I imagine the 2D plot as a "sticker" that can be put onto the cylinder, like a label on a bottle. That way, you can see the explanatory diagram itself wrap around the cylinder and become identical to the solution:

```
length = 12;
circumference = 4;
radius = circumference/(2 Pi);

s[x_] := Piecewise[{{4 Mod[x, 3]/3, 
    EvenQ[Quotient[x, 3]]}, {4 Mod[x, 3]/3, True}}]
plot = Plot[s[x], {x, 0, 12}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed, 
   Epilog -> {{Green, Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], 
      Arrow[{{0, 0.1}, {3, 0.1}}], Text["3 cm", {1.5, 0.2}]}, {Purple,
       Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], Text["4 cm", {3.7, 2}], 
      Arrow[{{3.2, 0}, {3.2, 4}}], Text["3 cm", {1.5, 0.2}]}, {Orange,
       Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], Arrow[{{-0.2, 0}, {2.8, 4}}], 
      Text["5 cm", {1, 2.2}]}}, Axes -> None, Frame -> None, 
   BaseStyle -> {Thick, Larger}, Background -> LightYellow, 
   ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> circumference/length, 
   ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, FrameTicks -> None];

openPrism[pts_List, h_] := Module[
  {bottoms, tops, surfacePoints, sidePoints, n},
  surfacePoints = Table[
    Map[PadRight[#, 3, height] &, pts], {height, {0, h}}];
  {bottoms, tops} = {Most[#], Rest[#]} &@surfacePoints;
  sidePoints = 
   Most@Flatten[{bottoms, RotateLeft[bottoms, {0, 1}], 
      RotateLeft[tops, {0, 1}], tops}, {{2, 3}, {1}}];
  n = Length[sidePoints];
  MapThread[
   Polygon[#1, VertexNormals -> (#1 - #2), 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> #3] &,
   {sidePoints,
    Map[{0, 0, 1} # &, sidePoints, {2}],
    Table[{{i/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 0}, {(i + 1)/n, 1}, {i/n, 1}}, {i, 0,
       n - 1}]
    }]
  ]

openCyl[{pt1_, pt2_}, r_, {θ1_, θ2_}, n_: 90] := 
 Module[{circle = 
    r Table[{Cos[ϕ], 
       Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, θ1, θ2, (θ2 - θ1)/n}], 
   h = EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]}, 
  GeometricTransformation[openPrism[circle, h], 
   Composition[TranslationTransform[pt1], 
    Quiet[Check[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1.}, pt2 - pt1}], 
      Identity]]]]]

img = Rasterize[Rotate[plot, 90 Degree], ImageSize -> 500];

Manipulate[
 With[{r = radius + x^2},
  Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.7], Specularity[White, 20], Darker[Red], 
     Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 13}}, .99 radius]},
    {FaceForm[Texture[img], Gray], EdgeForm[], 
     openCyl[{{radius - r, 0, 0}, {radius - r, 0, 12}}, 
      r, {0, 2 Pi radius/r}]}}, Boxed -> False, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral", ViewPoint -> {4, -2, -4}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0, -1, 0}, SphericalRegion -> True]],
 {x, 0, 5}
 ]
```

[image: animation]

What I did here is modify another answer to [How to add texture to solid Graphics3D object such as cylinder?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52336/245) in such a way that the cylinder can be open, by adding the ability to specify an angle interval.

The 2D diagram is rasterized and used as a `Texture`, inside `FaceForm` so that I can make the back of the label gray (you only see that if you do a 3D rotation - the `ViewPoint` by default is chosen so as to show only the front of the label).

**Edit**

In this animation, the wrapped label is created with the function

```
openCyl[{pt1, pt2}, r, {θ1, θ2}, n]
```

It creates a cylindrically warped polygon by extruding a circle segment of radius `r` beginning at polar angle `θ1` and ending at polar angle `θ2`. The orientation and height of this partial cylinder is dictated by `{pt1, pt2}` which is a pair of three-dimensional points that form the beginning and end of the cylinder axis. The last argument `n` is optional and defines the number of polygons along the side wall.

*Speed considerations*

The `Manipulate` as defined above runs completely smoothly on my laptop with *Mathematica* version 8, but it's choppy in version 10. To make the animation more responsive if necessary, here are three methods:

The easiest speed improvement is to decrease the number of polygons in `openCyl` from its default value `90` to a smaller number, e.g., `30`. This will still give a smooth display because `openCyl` creates the warped polygon with `VertexNormals` that allow the rendering engine to give the illusion of a smooth surface. With fewer polygons, the rendering speed goes up.

For any kind of animation involving only a single parameter (like the "wrapping stage" `x` here), `Manipulate` is usually overkill because `Animate` and `ListAnimate` allow you to explore a one-parameter family of plots equally well. When the drawing of each frame is sluggish, it's better to create the frames as a `List` beforehand, and then feed it into `ListAnimate` to do the actual animation of the pre-computed frames.

Another factor that can improve the responsiveness is to decrease the `ImageSize` in the texture `img` from `500` to a smaller value like `200`. I chose a large `ImageSize` to get a smoothly rendered texture, but there's always a tradeoff between quality and speed.

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: @Jens thank you...I will wait a little but this is beautiful indeed...definitely upvote and likely accept

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks for the question - it gave me the idea to write a the `openCyl` function, and I think this may come in handy in other applications as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 12}}, 2/π]],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  2/π {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 3 θ/4}, 
  {θ, 0, 8 π} ,
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Though this is correct for a cylinder of radius 1 and length 4 and could be adapted to the conditions of the puzzle it does not facilitate the insight for someone solving the puzzle...the point of my visualisation I already know the answer and it almost leaps from the graphic

Comment: To be explicit using 4 Sqrt[9+16]= 20 cm