# Draw phase portrait with StreamPlot on a sphere

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d

I would like to draw this phase portrait using `StreamPlot` on sphere as in this picture
[image]
like that

[image]

In fact, i have seen this for the classical pendulum defined by [enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/phase-portrait-on-a-cylinder?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> None, StreamPoints -> Fine, AspectRatio -> 0.8, Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{0, 0}, {\[Pi], 0}, {-\[Pi], 0}}]}]
```

It have defined   `cyl` [enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/how-to-add-texture-to-solid-graphics3d-object-such-as-cylinder/52336#52336) with a complicated transformation on that.

Comment: On a sphere or on a cylinder?

Comment: What do `x` and `y` represent? To draw a phase portrait on a sphere you need a vector field (or ODE) on a sphere. In the cylinder example, the field/ODE is invariant under the transformation $x \mapsto x+2\pi$, which allows one to map the vector field $(\dot x, \dot y) = (y, -\sin x)$ on the plane to a vector field on a cylinder. There's no such natural mapping onto the sphere, so you would have to define one.

Answer (score 9):

```
texture = 
 StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> None, 
  StreamPoints -> Fine, AspectRatio -> 0.8, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, 
    Point[{{0, 0}, {π, 0}, {-π, 0}}]}]
ParametricPlot3D[
 FromSphericalCoordinates[{1, θ, φ}] // 
  Evaluate, {θ, 0, Pi}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[texture], TextureCoordinateScaling -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks, could you modify this in order to get a sphere as above and draw a data points on it.

Comment: In my personal opinion you try to answer an incorrect question which makes no sense. It's unclear to me what `StreamPlot` on the sphere is at all

Comment: @user64494 He wan to draw a portrait onto a sphere instead of a vector fields on sphere,so we need not consider vector field.

Comment: @cvgmt: It's unclear what portrait should be drawn. I repeat you try to answer an ill-posed question (see the Michael E2's comment to the question). Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.