# To change the pattern of sphere surface in Graphic3D

Tags: graphics

I used of this command to draw a sphere

```
Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 50], ColorData["Atoms", "Ag"], 
Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .7]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

How can I change the pattern of that as meshing or something else not as this case simple. In fact, if we assume this shape as earth, the desired case is to plot this earth with its Meridian lines and Earth orbits lines (as mesh lines) on the surface with a flexible distances (angels) far away each others.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52/texture-mapping-and-resizing-a-sphere-primitive-in-mathematica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
latitude[r_, a_] := 
 Line[Table[{r Cos[a] Sin[b], r Sin[a] Sin[b], r Cos[b]}, {b, 0, 
    2 Pi, .1}]]
longitude[r_, b_] := 
 Line[Table[{r Cos[a] Sin[b], r Sin[a] Sin[b], r Cos[b]}, {a, 0, 
    2 Pi, .1}]]
orbit[r_, a_, incline_] := Rotate[latitude[r, a], incline, {1, 0, 0}]
Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 0.5], ColorData["Atoms", "Ag"], 
  Sphere[], Brown, latitude[1, #] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/8], 
  longitude[1, #] & /@ Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/8], Red, 
  orbit[2, Pi/6, Pi/3]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html) has a [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) option.

```
RegionQ[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .7]]

(*  True  *)

RegionPlot3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .7],
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Boxed -> False,
 PlotStyle -> {
   Specularity[White, 100],
   ColorData["Atoms", "Ag"]},
 Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I have to have just meshes not the surface. I delete the Plotstyle but one yellow surface has been kept!!